# hide ul li input text in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have included given code

```
<ul class="list-group" data-hook="" id="payment-method-fields">
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <label>
        <input checked="checked" id="method_id_4" type="radio" value="4">
        Credit Card
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <label>
        <input id="method_id_5"  type="radio" value="5">
        Test Paypal
        <div class="logo">
          <img src="/assets/icons/icon-paypal.png">
        </div>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <label>
        <input id="method_id_6"  type="radio" value="6">
        Check
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <label>
        <input id="method_id_15"  type="radio" value="15">
        Ali pay
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Now I want to hide Ali Pay when country is india

```
var country = $('.currentCountry').attr('value');
if (country=='India') {
}
```

please guide me how to this i am retrieving this above list dynamically. If country is india then i dont want to show

```
<li class="list-group-item">
          <label>
            <input id="method_id_15"  type="radio" value="15">
            Ali pay
          </label>
        </li>
```

In this id changes dynamically so we cannot do this with the help of id Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried to use .hide() function?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.toggle(boolean)` with `:contains(text)`:

```
$('#payment-method-fields li:contains(Ali pay)').toggle($(".currentCountry").val() !== "India");
```

Comment: the condition should be `!= 'India'`, but otherwise +1

Comment: @billyonecan ohh! missed it, you are absolutely correct.